# DB2 ROLLFORWARD ERROR when doing "TO A POINT IN TIME" option

Tags: backup, db2, logs, restore

I do restore command of backup image which was made 03.03.2015 at 19:20:

```
db2 restore database maxdb71 from "/data/archiveBackup" taken at 20150303192002 without prompting;
```

Then I try to do the rollforward to a point in time (03.03.2015 at 21:05) so this is after the backup image:

```
db2 rollforward db maxdb71 to 2015-03-03-21.05.00.000000 using local time and complete;
```

But I receive error:

```
SQL4970N  Roll-forward recovery on database "MAXDB71" cannot reach the 
specified stop point (end-of-log or point-in-time) on database partition(s) 
"0". Roll-forward recovery processing has halted on log file "S0000189.LOG".
```

So like it cannot find log  S0000189.LOG.
But this log EXISTS in the archive log location (C0000004 currently subfolder is used for archive logs) `/data/archive/ctginst1/MAXDB71/NODE0000/C0000004>:`

these are the timestamps for some of archive log files:

```
ctginst1 db2iadm1 15765504 2015-03-03 19:22 S0000187.LOG
ctginst1 db2iadm1 16785408 2015-03-03 21:52 S0000188.LOG
ctginst1 db2iadm1 16785408 2015-03-04 00:15 S0000189.LOG
ctginst1 db2iadm1 16785408 2015-03-04 02:32 S0000190.LOG
```

Basically log file S0000188.LOG should be the one which contains transactions from 21.05, right?

So why I cannot do the rollforward of point in time when I have necessary logs?
I am really confused with this rollforward option.

When I do `db2 rollforward database maxdb71 to end of logs and complete;`
it is successful and I get information:

```
 Log files processed                    = S0000187.LOG - S0000188.LOG
```

So `to end of logs` works but why I cannot perform until some specific point in time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you archive logs to a location different from the active log directory (`logpath` database configuration parameter), you need to specify the clause `overflow log path /path/to/archived/logs`. The `ROLLFORWARD` command does not do it automatically.

PS. You *really* should start reading manuals -- they are full of useful stuff, including multiple examples...

Comment: I succeeded to do the rollforward I added additional double quotes db2 rollforward db maxdb71 to 2015-03-03-21.05.00.000000 using local time and stop overflow log path "(/data/archive/)";  so thank you for help... but I am really confused when doing "end of logs" then database is smart enough to find all necessary archive logs, right? why is then not smart enough to find all necessary archive logs in case when doing the "point-in-time"??? I am confused why overflow must be mentioned because when doing rollforward END OF LOGS it is not necessary to do that

Comment: just to summarize FINAL QUESTION: why in case of POINT IN TIME db does not automatically reads ARCHIVE LOG folder (overflow must be specified) while in the case of END OF LOGS it is "smart" enough to look for ARCHIVE FOLDER on which after that it do the rollforward of archive logs until the end of them???

Comment: @Dejan - When rolling forward to end of logs without specifying `overflow log path` only active logs will be read.

Comment: @@mustaccio If my backup is at Monday 23:00 and archive logs are covering Tuesday, Wednesday and Thursday, and active logs are from Friday, if I do "to end of logs"  without specifying overflow log path what will be restored? Data from Monday and Friday but not and from Tuesday, Wednesday and Thursday??? I am really confused I read a lot I think I figured it out but now I am totally confused. This does not make sense to me. What data will be restored in this simple use case when using END OF LOGS? Thank you!!!

Comment: @@mustaccio can you please comment my last post? thank you very much

Comment: You're confusing _restore_ and _rollforward_. A _restore_ always brings back only what is contained in the backup image -- in your example data as of Monday 23:00. `rollforward .. to end of logs` will fail, because DB2 will not find log entries between the end of backup (Monday) and active logs (Friday), unless you specify where the missing logs are, and your database will remain in the "rollforward pending" mode.

Comment: I understand the difference between restore and rollforward. You mentioned it will failed. But it did not for this real use case, I really had backup from yesterday at 19:20 and I had 10 archive log files after that till this morning... I had also active log files and my command "to end of logs" was successful, I performed it today at 11:00. That is why I am still confused. You said it will fail but it did not fail and I did not user "overflow" when using "to end of logs".   In almost every example I saw on the web "to end of logs" option is not used with "overflow" option